# How do I monitor real time USB bandwith in windows 11?

Tags: windows, usb, bandwidth, analysis, app

Many suggest USBDeview but I do not see where that app displays any bandwith information. All I want is a way to monitor how much of the 480mb/s of my USB 2.0 port is being used and by which devices. Sort of like a task manager but with USB Mb/s usage. There is also an article that suggests looking under device manager, right clicking properties on the desired device and opening a supposed "power" tab that does not exist. I am aware of some linux solutions but not windows.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do a USB packet capture with WireShark and then use the IO graphs window
https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChStatIOGraphs.html

If you want a break down per port / device you might need to setup a filter in Wireshark using the usb.src, device_address or usb.endpoint_number fields.

```
usb.device_address == 2 and usb.endpoint_number == 2
```

See also
https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/u/usb.html